# How to read one single line of csv data in Python?

Tags: python, csv, file, iterator

There is a lot of examples of reading csv data using python, like this one:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

I only want to read one line of data and enter it into various variables. How do I do that? I've looked everywhere for a working example.

My code only retrieves the value for i, and none of the other values

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
  i = int(row[0])
  a1 = int(row[1])
  b1 = int(row[2])
  c1 = int(row[2])
  x1 = int(row[2])
  y1 = int(row[2])
  z1 = int(row[2])
```

Comment: what is the structure of your csv? What is `row` when you are iterating through reader?

Answer (score 173):

To read only the first row of the csv file use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the reader object.

```
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  row1 = next(reader)  # gets the first line
  # now do something here 
  # if first row is the header, then you can do one more next() to get the next row:
  # row2 = next(f)
```

or :

```
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    # do something here with `row`
    break
```

Comment: What happens if you want to just read the first line rather than iterating? This approach moves the iterator to the next line and you'll lose the value if you want to iterate over the whole list again later.

Comment: @MahsanNourani The file pointer can be moved to anywhere in the file, `file.seek(0)` will move it back to the start for example and then you can re-read from start. You'll have to keep the file open obviously to perform seek operation.

In general, the point of using iterators is that you'll get one item a time, hence saving memory, if you need multiple iteration on the same data, list is a better datastructure.

Comment: I was just trying to print the first line of the file before doing anything with the data hence my question! This solution is great, I didn't know that. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 47):

you could get just the first row like:

```
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
  csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
  first_line = next(csv_reader)
```

Comment: Probably, it is good to add "with open('csv_file', 'r')" as f: csv_reader = csv.reader(f) ..."

Answer (score 30):

You can use Pandas library to read the first few lines from the huge dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("names.csv", nrows=1)
```

You can mention the number of lines to be read in the nrows parameter.

Answer (score 19):

Just for reference, a `for` loop can be used after getting the first row to get the rest of the file:

```py
with open('file.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row1 = next(reader)  # gets the first line
    for row in reader:
        print(row)       # prints rows 2 and onward
```

Answer (score 17):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples):

> And while the module doesn’t directly support parsing strings, it can easily be done:

```
import csv
for row in csv.reader(['one,two,three']):
    print row
```

Just drop your string data into a singleton list.

Answer (score 8):

The simple way to get any row in csv file

```
import csv
csvfile = open('some.csv','rb')
csvFileArray = []
for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '.'):
    csvFileArray.append(row)
print(csvFileArray[0])
```

Comment: To make this work in python3, just remove the 'b' in 'rb'

Comment: This just works, actually without the `delimiter='.'`.

Comment: To answer the posters question, just add a `break` after the `csvFileArray.append(row)` and it will only read the first line.

Answer (score 6):

> **To print a range of line, in this case from line 4 to 7**
>
> ```
> import csv
>
> with open('california_housing_test.csv') as csv_file:
>     data = csv.reader(csv_file)
>     for row in list(data)[4:7]:
>         print(row)
> ```

Comment: I only got this to work by using `with open('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\csv_file.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:` as the first line

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is the best way, and in this case (and in most others) is one without using external libraries (pandas) or modules (csv). So, here is the simple answer.

```
""" no need to give any mode, keep it simple """
with open('some.csv') as f:
    """ store in a variable to be used later """
    my_line = f.nextline()
    """ do what you like with 'my_line' now """
```

Answer (score -1):

For Python3 use:
my_line = next(f)