# Why Does This Code Produce a List of Lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, import

I have a function:

```
def csvToList( filename ):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp)
        myList = list(reader)
    return myList
```

and call it with:

```
fruitList = csvToList('fruit.csv')
```

The contents of fruit.csv is:

```
apple,orange,kiwi,tomato
```

The value of fruitList is a list of lists:

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'tomato']]
```

Why does this code produce a list of lists and not just a simple "flat" list, like this:

```
['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'tomato']
```

Comment: Because each row in a file is a list, and you can have 0 or more rows?

Comment: Because there can be multiple rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read one single line of csv data in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262256/how-to-read-one-single-line-of-csv-data-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The reader produces *rows* from a CSV file. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.

It doesn't matter here that your file only consists of 1 row; `list(reader)` produces a list of *all* the rows, be that 0, 1 or 20 million. So a file with just 1 row gives you a list containing that single row as a list.

If you only ever expect one row, iterate one step with the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
def csvToList( filename ):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp)
        return next(reader, [])
```

`next(reader, [])` tells the function to return an empty list if `reader` doesn't produce anything at all.

Comment: If you only expect one row, what's the difference between returning `next()` or `reader[0]`?

Comment: @Idlehands: `reader` is not a sequence, you can't us indexing. It is an *iterable*.

Comment: Derp, just because it was an iterable I assumed it automatically supported indexing.  Thanks for clearing that up.  Should get more familiar with `csv` module.