# How to remove double quote from a csv file before reading it?

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the following error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: '|' expected after '"'

The reason is because the first line has `'"'` that shouldn't be there:

```
"Name|Kind|Color|Price
```

I tried the following:

```
`pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', usecols=fields, engine='python')`
```

Which produces the above error.

```
pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', usecols=fields, engine='python', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
```

This doesn't work because it drops the whole line which I need because it's column headers.

Is there a way to fix this without rewriting the file? Maybe read it into a string and remove `'"',` but then how do I read that string with the following?

```
pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', usecols=fields, engine='python')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure about your problem but given a csv file like:

```
"Name|Kind|Color|Price
alex|robot|braun|100$
```

then the following code will remove any leading "#" if present:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re


pd.DataFrame([
    re.match(r'"*(?P<line>.*)', line)
    .group("line")
    .split("|")
    for line in open("tmp.csv").readlines()
])


# 
#       0      1      2      3
# 0  Name   Kind  Color  Price
# 1  alex  robot  braun   100$
```

Answer (score 0):

You understand the issue.

Read the first line separately (see [Ashwini Chaudhary's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17262302/9214459))
Once you have the line, remove the double quote and split the line using your separator.

```
# Initialize your separator and filename
sep = '|'
filename = 'some.csv'

# Read the first line and remove the double quote

with open(filename, newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  row1 = next(reader)  
  cols = row1.replace('"','').split(sep)
```

Using the `cols` list, perform the pandas.read_csv, skipping the first line (no header row) and specify the column names using the `cols` list you just extracted.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, 
                 sep=sep, 
                 skiprows=1, 
                 header=0, 
                 names=cols, 
                 engine='python')
```

The read_csv assumes you want to use all the  columns defined in the first row by separators.  If you want to use only a subset, the `cols` list will need to be adjusted and `use_cols` will need to be specified.